# Count the number of times an element is greater than its previous element in a list

Tags: list, count, racket

I am trying to use the ability to have multiple "then-expressions" for a conditional in cond but I've yet to be successful in that. The goal is to have a function take in a list and spit out the count.

```
 (define (countInc aList)
  (let ((count 0))
    (lambda ()
  (cond
    [(= (length aList) 0) '()]
    [(> (second aList) (first aList)) (set! count (+ count 1)) (countInc (rest aList))]
    (else (countInc (rest aList)))))))

(check-expect (countInc '(1 2 3 4 5 6)) 5)
```

To explain, answer is 5 because 2 > 1, 3 > 2, 4 > 3, 5 > 4, and 6 > 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that your base case is incorrect: you're returning an empty list, shouldn't we be returning the counter? By the way, your procedure is actually returning a `lambda` with no arguments, that's not what you want to do.

Also: you should never use `length` for determining if a list is empty, and in general you should avoid using `set!` unless strictly necessary - Scheme favors a functional-programming style.

What you want to do can be written without mutating state variables, the trick is to keep track of the previous element while traversing the list - and beware of the many edge cases!

```
(define (countInc lst)
  ; edge cases
  (if (or (empty? lst) (empty? (rest lst)))
      0
      ; use a named let or a helper procedure
      (let loop ((prev (first lst))
                 (lst  (rest lst)))
        (cond ((empty? (rest lst))  ; base case
               (if (> (first lst) prev) 1 0))
              ((> (first lst) prev) ; found one, count it
               (+ 1 (loop (first lst) (rest lst))))
              (else ; skip this one
               (loop (first lst) (rest lst)))))))
```

This works fine even for the edge cases, I've provided tests for them:

```
(countInc '())
=> 0
(countInc '(1))
=> 0
(countInc '(2 1))
=> 0
(countInc '(1 2))
=> 1
(countInc '(4 1 3 2 5 6))
=> 3
(countInc '(1 2 3 4 5 6))
=> 5
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm struggling to understand how racket processes instructions and really appreciate the tips!